# Is there any way to check the current variable status and other debugging methods?

Tags: javascript, debugging, variables

Is there any way to check the current variables value and such using some sort of debugger? I have an error in my code, and I want to see if it is a variable causing it, and if not, I would like to figure out what is. What are some really good debuggers for JS anyone knows of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with gpmattoo Firebug is great.  Internet Explorer has a javascript debugger built in (hit F12) Chrome has one built in too but there is also a [Firebug lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) that should work if you like Firebug for Firefox

Comment: Yes, Firebug and FirePHP for AJAX debugging.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at Firebug http://getfirebug.com/

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio (and Visual Web Developer) has support for JS debugging.

More lightweight, however, you can probably find something that'll plug in to your browser.  IE has a JS debugger built-in (as of IE8 I think), Firebug is probably the way to go in Firefox, and I'm pretty sure Chrome also has a built-in debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) under Firefox or the chrome inspector (right click on the page and inspect...) under Chrome. 
You will then need to use some logging if the variable is a local one (`console.log()`)